# Spring boot upgrade from 2.6.7 to higher version and not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I upgrade spring boot 2.6.7 to 2.7.4 or higher version, I am getting the date is not parsed in server console. When I looked the zipped jar file of my service, i could see bytebuddy doesnt have Date modified timestamp and server got failed to start.Other all jars have the date modified timestamp. PFB the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtMYk.png)

Excluded the bytebuddy and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrading please check the compatibility of the libraries used in the project.
While upgrading you can refer release document of the version for deprecation/removal of classes and libraries.